# Make calc with this syntax

Tags: javascript, function

```
function addnumbers(func) {

   return func(4, 6);

}
```

I was asked to make a calculator using this structure. How could I potentially make calculating functions happen inside this syntax using parameters? I just need simple math to happen like adding, subtracting, dividing, and multiplying.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a little like passing a function pointer to the function and calling it as a callback.

```
var add=function(a, b) {
    return a+b;
}

addnumbers(add); // returns 10
```

---

So if you put the function `add` as parameter for the function `addnumbers` you can exchange in mind the text `func` by `add`:

```
function addnumbers(add) {
   return add(4, 6);
}
```

If you call `addnumbers` with the parmeter `add` the function `addnumbers` call the function `add` with the parameters `4` and `6`. Now again inserted in the mind:

```
var add=function(4, 6) {
    return 4+6;
}
```

Than the function `add` will return `10` and the function `addnumbers` will return this value too.

Comment: The other functions are simple enough isn't it?

Comment: how does that return 10 if you didn't specify what a and b are? or did you just assume 4 and 6 to be a and b each time a and b are called?

Comment: @JakeE `a` and `b` are set in your `addnumbers` function as `4` and `6`.

Comment: how do i put the syntax together so they apply to eachother? thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. I'll try to explain how the calles are working.